# Constructive Proof to Show that Algebraic Numbers are Algebraically Closed

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, fields

**EDIT2:** After reading some papers, I think the question can best be rephrased as "How can the minimal polynomial for a polynomial with algebraic coefficients be calculated.  I have seen papers and textbooks that show that algebraic numbers are algrebraically closed, but I haven't seen a constructive proof.

> Let $f_n,f_{n-1},...,f_0$ be univariate polynomials with rational
>   coefficients.  For each $f_i$, assume that we have successfully
>   isolated a root $\lambda_i$ via Sturm's Theorem as the only root
>   within the range $[\lambda_i^-,\lambda_i^+]$.
>
> Define $g$ as the univariate polynomial:
>
> $$g(x) = \lambda_nx^n + \lambda_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + \lambda_0$$
>
> **Is it possible to isolate the zeros of $g$?  Specifically, is it possible to determine if $g$ has repeated roots?**
>
> I asked a somewhat similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186621/determining-roots-of-a-polynomial-with-interval-estimates-of-coefficients) in which each
>   $\lambda_i$ is represented as an interval whose size can be shrunk
>   arbitrarily (but not shrunk to a single point).  Alex Degtyarev
>   correctly pointed out that the problem cannot be solved if the values
>   of $\lambda_i$ are not known exactly.
>
> However, in this instance, the values are known exactly. 
>   Unfortunately, I'm missing how the rational coefficients of the $f_i$
>   can be incorporated in an algorithm to isolate the roots of $g$.
>
> Thanks for any help.
>
> **EDIT:**   Since posting the question, I've read a bit on Galois Theory, and it looks like this problem can be solved, although I'm
>   still trying to figure out exactly how.  I've figured out algorithms
>   to find the minimal polynomial for sums and products of algebraic
>   numbers.  I still haven't found a algorithm to determine the minimal
>   polynomial for a polynomial with algebraic coefficients although I
>   have found a [proof](http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/42022.pdf) that such a polynomial exists.

Comment: Are you sure this is not related to the recently famous story of interlacing polynomials?

Comment: I'm sorry, my background is in computer science, so I'm not up to date with the latest mathematical headlines.  I'll google "interlacing polynomials" and see what I can find.

Comment: Infact interlacing polynomials became big because of CS people! Look at Terence Tao's review of the solution to the Kadison-Singer conjecture. It was proven by Nikhil Srivastava, Daniel Spielman and Adam Marcus.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this? I am curious - since I too think of such stuff these days!

Comment: I'm working on an iterated cylindrical algebraic decomposition approach to prove decidability for robotic task and motion planning.  Previously, people have only considered 1 round of c.a.d., which means that all polynomial coefficients are rational.  In my approach, from the second round of c.a.d. on, the coefficients will be algebraic numbers in general.

Comment: The link at the end of the questions seems to be dead. My best guess would be that it is supposed to go to the PlanetMath article: [polynomial equation with algebraic coefficients](https://planetmath.org/polynomialequationwithalgebraiccoefficients).

Answer (score 2):

I found a constructive [proof](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066106001095).  It will be odd to use cylindrical algebraic decomposition (with rational polynomial coefficients) as a sub-algorithm for cylindrical algebraic decomposition (with algebraic polynomial coefficients), but it appears to work.

Comment: There might be some theory in http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html 
To my knowledge, quantifier elimination has really nasty complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I know the horrible complexity of quantifier elimination all too well.  Without getting into the parameteric details, the tentative run-time of my task and motion decidability result looks like $\omega(2^{2^{(2 \uparrow \uparrow k)^{(2 \uparrow \uparrow k)}}})$, but decidability is decidability.

Comment: I found a great paper outlining an explicit algorithm to solve the problem ([link](http://dl.acm.org.libproxy.mit.edu/citation.cfm?id=143312)).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the constructive proof provided by the Mathematical Components libraries, you will find further references in the comments.

http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/mathcomp-1.5/MathComp.algebraics_fundamentals.html

There is also a lot of documentation in Cyril's Cohen PhD thesis.

Best,
E